# How does the Inspire aced skill work (distance, interaction speed)?

Tags: payday-2

> INSPIRE
>
> BASIC
>
> You revive crew members faster. 50% increase to revive speed.
>
> ACE
>
> You can revive crew members **at a distance** by shouting at them.

Before I buy this expensive ace, I'd like to know exactly how it works.  I've been looking over Youtube to find some in-game examples, but didn't find anything concluding.

- Do I need to have a direct line of sight on my teammate?
- What's the distance to maintain with him in order to make the skill work?
- Is the speed the same than when you revive someone while standing next to him?
- Anything other pros or cons I should know about?

Comment: [This thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864977564210734675/) seems to highlight the fact that the target only recovers 25% of his life instead of 50%.  [This other one](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864976115110597746/) says it works through walls and floors, but people seem to think it only has a certain %age of chances to work...  The description definitely lacks of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inspire ability has a 100% chance to revive your teammate by shouting at them (20 second cooldown). You can revive through walls and floors by looking at them and shouting. I believe the range that this works over is tied into the range of your shout ability (which can be increased with the Mastermind third tier bonus).

The speed is faster than the usual method of reviving as shouting is an instant ability, when inspire procs your target will get up immediately. However, due to the way ranged targeting works in Payday 2, in the event there is another player (or enemies, if you're in line of sight) near the player that is downed it can be difficult to target the correct player.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Does it mean that it has a percentage chance to revive *everytime* you shout at a crew member?  Any idea of the %age?

Comment: yeah a percentage chance every time, I don't know on the rough percentages though